# ASP.net disallow name to be in Password Field

Tags: asp.net

I need the user entry in

```
tbName (textbox)
```

to not be allowed as a possible password in the password text box.

```
tbPass (textbox)
```

How do I go about this?  I have validation in the password field for 8 characters, 1 uppercase etc, but I need it to NOT allow the users name to be part of the password they are creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CompareValidator` with `NotEqual` option

```
           <asp:TextBox id="tbName" runat="server" />
           <asp:TextBox id="tbPass" runat="server" /><br>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" 
              ControlToValidate="tbName" 
              ErrorMessage="name required"/><br>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" 
              ControlToValidate="tbPass" 
              ErrorMessage="pass required"/><br>
           <asp:CompareValidator runat="server"
              ControlToValidate="tbName"
              ControlToCompare="tbPass"
              Type="String"
              Operator="NotEqual"
              ErrorMessage="Password cannot be the same as name" />
```

Comment: It isnt working, though I think it may be because I need it to reject it if the name is anywhere within the password (not just the password itself).

Comment: @CodedMe Then you should handle that in code-behind. Use `if (txtPass.Text.Contains(txtName.Text))`